# How to clone a file?

Tags: file, delphi, winapi, copy, delphi-2009

I want to make an identical copy of a file and I know how to copy the content of a file in a new file but I don't know how to copy the attributes and the dates.

I tried the following code but it doesn't work in Delphi 2009 :

```
SrcHandle:=CreateFile(PWideChar('\\?\'+SrcName), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, 0);
DestHandle:=CreateFile(PWideChar('\\?\'+DestName), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nil, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, SrcHandle);
```

Notice that the last parameter of the destination `CreateFile` is the handle of the sorce file. Delphi says if I do that it will copy "the attributes and extended attributes" to the new file. But it doesn't...

Comment: What's wrong with TFile.Copy?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think _marus nebunu_ wants to _"clone"_ (as in _create an identical copy including timestamps and attributes_) a file in **one step**. I don't know why does he want it but the documentation promises to do it for him and it does not. Does `TFile.Copy()` copies attributes and timestamps? (I really don't know, but I _think_ it does not.)

Comment: It copies attributes. File stamps need to be done separately. Why would you use CreateFile.

Comment: I suspect the api doesn't even refer to 'SrcHandle' with that call, as you can pass an invalid handle without problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TFile.Copy()` from `IOUtils`. The operating system provides file copying facilities and this function takes advantage of them. This function calls the Windows `CopyFile` function. You could call that directly if you'd rather.

Having copied the file this way, all the attributes will have been copied. The final step is the file timestamps. Use `GetFileTime` and `SetFileTime` to perform this step.

Comment: +1 this is the way to go. yet, still mystery remains why `hTemplateFile` does not function as documented in `CreateFile` api.

Answer (score 1):

Just set file attributes manually - [SetFileAttributes function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: [SetFileDate()](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=FileSetDate) could also come in handy.